# problem on identity theorem for analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

is the following statement true or false:

there exists no analytic function f in $\Bbb D$ (closed unit disk) such that f(z) is not identically zero on  $\Bbb D$ and f($\frac{ni^n}{n+1}$)=0.

i think the answer is true.the assertion is given below:

let f be analytic on $\Bbb D$.

since f($\frac{ni^n}{n+1}$)=0
and also $\frac{ni^n}{n+1}$ has limit points 1,-1,i,-i .so ,the above given set of zeroes has all limit points in $\Bbb D$.so,f(z) is  identically zero on  $\Bbb D$ which does not matches the above given condition

is this assertion correct??...

Comment: $\frac{ni^n}{n+1}\rightarrow\infty$ is not true (Do you mean that it doesn't converge?). These points have $\pm1,\pm i$ as limit points -- these still are not _inside_ $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: What does analytic in the closed unit disc mean?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb those points are inside $\mathbb D,$ as it is the closed unit disc. This is why I asked my question.

Comment: As @zhw. pointed out, it doesn't make sense to talk about being analytic at a boundary point, so really $f$ is analytic on the _interior_ of $\mathbb{D}$, which doesn't contain these limit points

Comment: Well often "analytic on a set" is defined to mean "analytic on a neighborhood of that set".

Comment: @charlestoncrabb:function is analytic on closed unit disk means function is analytic on an open set containing the unit disk, not what you are assuming...

Comment: I see, so then yes I agree that the theorem applies and shows $f$ must be identically zero.